# modalRef.hide() not close modal

Tags: angular

[my modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZgzB.jpg)

When clicked, the modal stays open and does not close.
This is my code

```
    close(option?: boolean | undefined) {
     this.confirmResult.next(option)
     this.modalRef.hide()
   }
```

Comment: Show where / how `modelRef` is defined. Also, are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: It might be because there is no function `hide`. Use the hints typescript gives you, or use material documentation